# Adjust Maximum Value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to give max value to variable. The variable should not exceeds it's maximum value. I don't know how to do it.
There is a javascript i created

```
var myvalue = 0
function click(){
  myvalue = myvalue + 10
  // I want to adjust max value for var myvalue that is 100.
  if (myvalue > 100){
  alert('this is max value')
  }
}
```

Please no JQuery. Only Javascript

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your variable to always stay within a range?

Comment: `myvalue = 100; alert('this is max value');`

Comment: You know the [Math.max, Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) function?, maybe could serve you

Comment: Doesn't the code you've shown already do what you want, except within the `if` you would need to assign `myvalue = 100;`?

Answer (score 1):

Asign the variable like this :

```
myValue = myValue < 100 ? myValue : 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure where you're going to take the variable, you could use "Math.min" to avoid the variable is greater than a number

```
var myvalue = 0
function click(){
    myvalue = myvalue + 10;
    myvalue = Math.min(myvalue, 100);
}

//Another examples
var foo = Math.min(35,100) //35
var foo = Math.min(545,100) //100
var foo = Math.min(125,100) //100
var foo = Math.min(12,100) //12
```

Answer (score 0):

put the statement which updates the value of your variable inside an `if`

```
var myvalue = 0;
function click() {
  if (myvalue < 100) {
    myvalue = myvalue + 10;
  }
  else {
    alert('this is max value');
  }
}
```